# ListView coloring of Rectangle in ViewBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, viewbox

I have a ListView which is binded to an ObservableCollection.

```
 <ListView 
            ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfObjects}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelctedObj}" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="1"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" FontSize="10"

            >

                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="15"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView >

                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" >
                            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Name" Command="{Binding SortCommand}" CommandParameter="Name"/>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <GridViewColumn Header="Color">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Viewbox Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Visibility="Visible"/>
                                    </Viewbox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                     </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

For each object in my collection, it should display the name of it and simply a red rectangle on the right hand side.

I dont know why, but when I start the application it only appears the name without any coloured rectangle.
Above is a very simplyfied version of my code. All my bindings are working, also others I implemented in ViewBoxes.
Does anyone has an idea what the critical point is?

Comment: Try giving the rectangle a height and width

Comment: Yes thats it, thank you for that hint. Couldn't figure it out the whole day. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the rectangle a height and width.